# Use specific local gcc and related libraries with Homebrew

Tags: install, homebrew, gcc

I would like to use Homebrew to install some stuff,

In the mean time, I have already installed my local gcc, and I want Homebrew to use this specific one (this gcc at `/usr/local/bin/gcc` is frequently upgraded by myself).

Unfortunately, Homebrew always figure out its gcc dependency, and related libraries, then download them all at `/usr/local/Cellar`.

For instance:

On my Mac, `which gcc` indeed points to `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, when I `brew install suite-sparse`, it downloads gcc-4.9.1, while I already have gcc-4.9.2 locally.

I just want to keep things simple, use my local gcc with the associated library, e.g. gmp and mpfr (at `/usr/local/lib`), is it possible with Homebrew?

Comment: That is not simple :) Homebrew and other packaging systems use an exact build of a tool so that they can test things work - versions of tools give different results and so would not work in the same way - especially compilers.

Comment: Why do you want that gcc and not Homebrew's - or why not use Apple's clang -- answer to this might help us give suggestions to help you

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. When you install `gcc`, you must satisfied the required dependencies, otherwise this packages will be installed to ensure that works property.

```
Required: gmp ✔, libmpc ✘, mpfr ✘, cloog ✘, isl ✘
```

Same occurs on linux system, you can install `gcc` without it's dependencies:

```
Depends: cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), binutils (>= 2.24), libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), libc6 (>= 2.14), libcloog-isl4 (>= 0.17), libgmp10, libisl10 (>= 0.10), libmpc3, libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clearly, my gcc is consistent with gmp, mpfr etc... And I woult like to use "this" gcc to compile other package installed by Homebrew, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's posible if you symlink `gcc` with `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`. Additionally you can edit the installation script (python) of each formula by `brew edit formula`.

Comment: I think I already do the symlink, and "which gcc" indeed point to /usr/local/bin/gcc, but Homebrew still download its own dependent gcc, for example, when I "brew install suite-sparse", it downloads gcc-4.9.1, while I alreadyhave gcc-4.9.2 locally

Comment: Maybe the `suite-sparse` needs this version of `gcc`, check it with `brew edit suite-sparse`.