# i tried symlinking the existing package into /usr/local/bin but homebrew still keeps trying to download its own version which results in failure

Tags: terminal, homebrew, symlink

I know from questions like [Use specific local gcc and related libraries with Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173908/use-specific-local-gcc-and-related-libraries-with-homebrew) that this apparently isn't something easy to do, but that particular question seems to have been resolved with "why not just let brew install its own version of the dependency?"

My problem is I can't go that route, because brew fails every time it tries to install its own version of a dependency (ghc and cabal).  However I have managed to successfully install ghc and cabal in another way and they work fine from the terminal when i use their commands outside of brew.  I even symlinked those commands into /usr/local/bin, which supposedly is how you get brew to use existing commands, but still when I try to install anything that has ghc as a dependency, it tries to download its own version of it, and fails.

The failure, btw, seems to be because I am on an outdated version of MacOS.  But nevertheless i DO have a working version of ghc and cabal that meet the version requirements of the thing I am trying to install.  Surely there must be a workaround to get homebrew to just use the friggin existing version of the package already installed in the terminal, i hope?

OH, and i also tried using --ignore-dependencies but that doesn't seem to work because one of the dependencies ALSO has ghc as a dependency, so when i try to do all the non-ghc dependencies separately, a couple of those won't install either because they try to install ghc and fail.

Comment: This is a bit low on detail regarding the reasons brew fails, but most likely you get a conflict from having Homebrew install binaries into /usr/local/bin which already exist there. One way out would be to install non-Homebrew stuff to another place (e.g. /opt/bin) and let Homebrew install/manage its dependencies.